# Golang: unit testing fuction depenent on io.File.Write()

Tags: go, testing, io

Hеllo, fellow Gophers!

Learning how to write unit tests and got stuck. Please, don't beat me up, cause I am new to this. I've googled and read a lot, but I still couldn't come up with a proper solution.
The exercise is to write a unit test for a function I wrote:

[Filecopy](https://github.com/no-to-mediocrity/Learning_GO/blob/main/gocopy/main.go)(pathfrom, pathto string, limit, offset int64) error

The simplified function will look like this

```
source, err := os.Open(pathfrom)
    destination, err := os.Create(pathto)
    buf := make([]byte, *buffersize)
    for {
        n, err := source.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return err
        }
        if _, err := destination.Write(buf[pos:n]); err != nil {
            return err
            if n == 0 {
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have to unit test it. And it's not going well. There are two ways I could test it:

1. Provide it a real temp file with a predetermined contents, so the test function would know what to expect after the execution. Should work, but I read this option is NOT the way to unit test properly as it touches the FS.
2. Use fake FS. I've tried testing files generated by mapfs and afero, but no luck, my function doesn't work with it (it works with real files though), either I am doing something wrong.

Please tell me how to unit test my function properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Point 1 is pretty much okay because it's nothing wrong as long as you're working with FS in a controlled manner: the `io/ioutil` contains functions to work with temporary files and directories. Point 2 is arguably better but it requires your code which is to work with filesystems to not use the `os` package directly but rather be organized around _a set of interfaces_ which represent a file system as a concept. Since v1.17 Go provides such set in its `io/fs` package. …

Comment: …With this approach, you basically inject "real" implementation of the FS access layer into your code in normal mode (when the function is used as part of the program) or "fake" impelementation—when testing. IMHO (basically, that's the reason your question is unfit for SO: it's bound to generate opinionated responses) virtualizing the FS does not really worth the trouble unless you're about doing really cool stuff during your testing—like controlled fault injection (required to write robust SW, like databases). …

Comment: … Also consider that sometimes you need to test code depending on 3rd-party packages which do use the `os` package to manipulate files; in such cases there is hardly any sensible way to not use controlled temporary directories on a real FS.

Comment: While we're at it, please read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for asking questions on SO, and consider [other venues](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community) to ask questions like this one about Go.

Comment: "but I read this option is NOT the way to unit test properly as it touches the FS." This is a common misunderstanding. Chances that your code runs in an environment _without_ a filesystem are low. Your environment _will_ have a CPU, RAM, Filesystem and Loopback device and avoiding "the FS" in unit tests is as clever as avoiding (and faking/mocking) your RAM.

Comment: The advice of not using the FS during unit tests stems from the bad practice of using FS stuff not under the control of the unit test like accessing /usr/dict/words or assuming certain directories to be present which will break (at least in the long run).  Testfiles and directories under your control, properly versioned simply are not a problem.

Comment: Option 3 would be to move the first two lines outside the function and have it take an `io.Reader` source and `io.Writer` destination; since you said your snippet is simplified, it's hard to say if this is the right approach, but it often is.